# Java Form Loaded With Errors - Netbeans

Tags: java, forms, netbeans

I'm pretty new to netbeans and I've ran into this problem:
[When i try to open my netbeans project this shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWLBi.png)

It also gives me A LOT of exceptions

I have no clue on how to solve this

Tysm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it works.

First, go to Tools-> Choose Option->In Advanced Options->Click Option then Editing and GUI Builder, where you need to set the Layout Generation.

To ensure the Swing Layout Extension library is not part of project

you can clean build/remove project/check java is in correct path/reinstall net beans
BTW why dont you try intellij community edition

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark since I had a similar problem once: I tried to pre-inialize a combobox with some values. Those values were supposed to come out of a (in-memory) database. The database was not available when using the NetBeans designer and therefore the designer could not construct the form and crashed.

So, check if your constructor contains code that has any dependency that works only in a certain environment.

Do NOT use "Allow Editing" if you are not knowing what you are doing / don't have a copy of your source. NetBeans will mess up your form.

Comment: I've solved.
I compiled the code using another compiler and then reuploaded on netbeans.
It seems to work.